# Send a value to woocommerce with a button type submit

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, forms

I'm using wp-crowdfunding extension, and i'm overriding a file called "fund-campaign-btn.php".

what it does : display a field and a button, so you can type your price and click on the button to send your price to the checkout page of woocommerce.

In my case I changed it a bit, instead of a blank field I made a list of prices, so the user click on the price he want, then click on the button. The list work but i can't figured out why when i click on the button, it send '0' to my checkout.

Here the original code :

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="cart">
                <?php do_action('before_wpneo_donate_field'); ?>
                <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); ?>
                <input type="number" step="any" min="0" placeholder="<?php echo $recomanded_price; ?>" name="wpneo_donate_amount_field" class="input-text amount wpneo_donate_amount_field text" value="<?php echo $recomanded_price; ?>" data-min-price="<?php echo $min_price ?>" data-max-price="<?php echo $max_price ?>" >
                <?php do_action('after_wpneo_donate_field'); ?>

                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" name="add-to-cart">
                <button type="submit" class="<?php echo apply_filters('add_to_donate_button_class', 'wpneo_donate_button'); ?>"><?php _e('Back Campaign', 'wp-crowdfunding'); ?></button>
 </form>
```

Here my code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="cart">
                <?php do_action('before_wpneo_donate_field');
                   $valAction = get_field('valeur_dune_action_admin_section');
                    $nbactions = 500000 / $valAction;
                ?>

                      <select type="number" step="any" name="actions" id="actions-select" name="wpneo_donate_amount_field" class="input-text amount wpneo_donate_amount_field text">
                       <?php 
                        $i = 1;
                        if ($nbactions != 0)
                        {
                            while ($i <= $nbactions) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $valAction * $i . '">' . $valAction * $i . '</option>';
                            $i++;
                            }
                        }

                            ?>
                        </select>

                <?php 
                echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();

                do_action('after_wpneo_donate_field'); ?>

                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo esc_attr($post->ID); ?>" name="add-to-cart">


                <button type="submit" class="<?php echo apply_filters('add_to_donate_button_class', 'wpneo_donate_button'); ?>"><?php _e('Back Campaign', 'wp-crowdfunding'); ?></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the select tag you have 2 name attribute

```
<select type="number" step="any" name="actions" id="actions-select" name="wpneo_donate_amount_field" class="input-text amount wpneo_donate_amount_field text">
```

Then, when you submit, it only collect the first defined name. (name="actions"). You have to delete this attribute. and using name="wpneo_donate_amount_field" only.

It should like

```
<select type="number" step="any" id="actions-select" name="wpneo_donate_amount_field" class="input-text amount wpneo_donate_amount_field text">
```

Comment: Rofl i'm so stupid ! didn't saw that, that works thanks you so much ! :)